# Why is my mySQL insert not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Some information is submited to this page via a PHP form, but when I publish it I get this error...

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-code) VALUES ('','$title','$description','$post','$author','11th September 20' at line 1
```

Anyone know why this is?

```
<?php
    $description = addslashes($_POST[description]);
    $post = addslashes($_POST[post]);
    $title = addslashes($_POST[title]);
    $date_posted = date("jS F Y");

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","********","**********");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO posts 
            (id, title, description, 
            post, author, date_posted, 
            category, image-code)
        VALUES
            ('','$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]',
            '$_POST[post]','$_POST[author]','$date_posted',
            '$_POST[category]','$image')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    echo "Draft Successfully Submitted!";
    mysqli_close($con);
    header("Location:queue.php");
?>
```

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this. You cannot keep ignoring this important advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to have dashes in your column names you must wrap them in ticks:

```
`image-code`
```

Otherwise it looks like the subtraction operator.

Answer (score 0):

The code section above does not define $image, so it will be passed as a literal to MySQL.

Comment: $image is still in double quotes so it'll be evaluated to null if anything.